# Oracle 12c/EUSM: Creating user schema mapping with for a common user in CDB

Tags: authentication, ldap, oracle12c, oid

I'm trying to build up an EUS environment on Oracle 12c multitenancy(one CDB named "orcl" and one PDB named "pdb1" ) + OID 11.1.0.7 + WebLogic 10.3.6.

Both the CDB and PDB are registered with directory service.

There're two users created in OID:

cn=qa0user,cn=Users,dc=domain

cn=qa1user,cn=Users,dc=domain

and two global users created:

in CDB: C##SHARED_SCHEMA

in PDB: SHARED_SCHEMA

I've successfully created the user-schema mapping in PDB (qa1user to SHARED_SCHEMA):

```
$ ./eusm listMappings realm_dn="dc=domain" ldap_port="3060" ldap_host="orm01-wan-02-tunnel.domain" ldap_user_dn="cn=orcladmin" ldap_user_password="Password123" database_name="pdb1_orcl"

LIST OF DATABASE SCHEMA MAPPINGS:
------------------------------------
Mapping Name:  MAPPING0
Mapping Type:  ENTRY
Mapping DN:    cn=qa1user,cn=Users,dc=domain
Mapping schema:SHARED_SCHEMA
Mapping Level :DATABASE
```

But there's an error of NoPermissionException when creating mapping in CDB:

```
 $ ./eusm createMapping realm_dn="dc=domain" ldap_port="3060" ldap_host="orm01-wan-02-tunnel.domain" ldap_user_dn="cn=orcladmin" ldap_user_password="Password123" database_name="orcl" map_type="ENTRY" map_dn="cn=qa0user,cn=Users,dc=domain" schema="C##SHARED_SCHEMA"

javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - Insufficient Access Rights]; remaining name 'cn=mapping0,cn=orcl,cn=OracleContext,dc=domain'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

your databases must be in branch *cn=OracleContext,dc=domain*. In the same level you must see Groups OU. 
The ldap_dn with which you create mappings must be a member of OracleContextAdmins group.

*dn: cn=OracleContextAdmins,cn=groups,cn=OracleContext,dc=domain
changetype: modify
add: uniquemember
uniquemember: cn=orcladmin*

You can refer https://appliedgeek.com/category/eus/ for more knowledge on how to trouble shoot EUS issues.

Comment: Thanks bbcr! This issue was confirmed as a bug by Oracle, and they're planing a fix on this.